# How to determine the connectivity number of a graph without being too "vague"?

Tags: graph-theory

Say, you have the Petersen graph,

[image]

and you would like to determine its connectivity number. One important result that we learnt is that a graph is $k$-connected iff for every vertices $u, v \in V(G)$, there exist $k$ paths that are vertex-independent. This result seems pretty useless though when it comes down to actually determining the connectivity number of the Petersen graph. Sure, I could look at it and feel like that for every two vertices, there exist exactly $3$ paths that are vertex-independent, but this doesn't seem to be rigorous enough. There is always the chance that I actually missed some specific scenario here.

So, how would I go about something like this (without trying to carefully write down every possible scenario, because this seems like quite a bit of work)? Is there any theorem that allows me to determine the connectivty number directly, not only for the Petersen graph, but in general?

Comment: For this specific case, there is a ton of symmetry in the graph, so have many fewer cases to check than you might think.  It may be possible to get bounds through applying to other theorems.  In general, it can be difficult (without directly computing an answer) to see how local changes in a graph change the global structure of the graph.

Comment: You're right, but I was rather interested in some kind of theorem that can be applicated on arbitrary graphs.

Comment: I would suggest that you try to rephrase your question to something like "What general results exist that can be used to bound the connectivity number of a graph"?

Comment: Hint: The number is at most $3$ since each vertex has degree $3$ (each path must leave a vertex through a different edge).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I rephrased it!

Comment: Well, you certainly can't always guess the connectivity of a graph by staring at it for 5 seconds, if that is what you're hoping for ;-). The amount of work required to determine the connectivity will grow as the complexity and number of vertices increases.

However, you can do better than simply trying every possible way to take paths from $u$ to $v$. I suggest looking at the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm for the max flow-min cut problem. Technically this is better for finding the edge connectivity, but it is somewhat related.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look into that.